# When write this code appear localhost redirected and This page isn’t working?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```
<?php  
include("connect.php");  
if(isset($_POST['submit']))  
{  
    $qonax=@$_POST['qonax'];  
    $subject=@$_POST['subject'];  
    $insert="INSERT INTO subject(ID,Qonax,Subject)VALUES('','$qonax','$subject')";  
    mysqli_query($link,$insert) or die(mysql_error($link));  
}  
header('location:insert_subject.php');  
?>
```

appear this:
[image]

This error appear when write `(if(isset($_POST['submit']){ }`
when removed this line code a problem fixed.

Comment: show the form too

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: i think you did header() redirection to the same file. Am i right.?

Comment: almost certainly you're redirecting back to the same script again, creating an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

move the redirection inside the if block and unsetting the  `$_POST['submit']` variable

```
<?php  
include("connect.php");  
if(isset($_POST['submit']))  
{  
    $qonax=@$_POST['qonax'];  
    $subject=@$_POST['subject'];  
    $insert="INSERT INTO subject(ID,Qonax,Subject)VALUES('','$qonax','$subject')";  
    mysqli_query($link,$insert) or die(mysql_error($link));
    unset($_POST['submit'])  
    header('location:insert_subject.php');
}  
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Taha, problem is fixed.

Comment: problem is fixed without using unset by entering header to the block:

Comment: Glad you fixed it :) probably you should find a way to close this thread and mark it as solved.